# Trying to add a blank <option> with jQuery from a dropdown with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JS function which populates a select based on the value of a first select, but I would like to add an empty `<option>` at the beginning.

This is the function

```
function createParkFloorMenu(){
      $('#idPark').on('change',function(event) {
           var parks = $(this).val();

           $.get(floorListUrl, {
             idPark: parks
           }, function(response) {

             var select = $('#idPiano');

             select.find('option').remove();

             $.each(response, function(i, v) {
               $('<option>').val(v.idPiano).text(v.nomePiano).appendTo(select);

             });
           });

         });
}
```

I tried to add

```
 $('option').val('').text('Seleziona Piano').appendTo($('#idPiano'));
```

with no success because it populates all the dropdown in my form with "Seleziona Piano" options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('option')` will find the `<option>` tags in your dom. If you want to create a new `option` tag - you need to use `$('<option>')` (like you already have in your code).

You can use:

```
 $('<option>').val('').text('').appendTo(select);
```

in your code right after the `remove()` part.